# Why is my simple Kafka Consumer example not working

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am facing issues in getting a very basic kafka consumer to work. I am using the kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar

Here is all that I have done.

1. Started zookeeper on command line (All commands are run from  )

`zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties`

2. Started Kafka server

`kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties`

3. Created a new topic 'hellotopic' and verified it by listing the topics

`kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic hellotopic
Created topic "hellotopic".`

Verify by listing the topics

`D:\RC\Softwares\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
hellotopic`

4. Post message to the topic and verified the same on console consumer

`kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic hellotopic --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"`

Message key and value entered as below

`key1:value1`

You can see that on the console consumer we are able to see the message in topic 'hellotopic'

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic hellotopic --from-beginning
```

Output for above command is as shown below. We can see the message value 'value1' that was posted

`Using the ConsoleConsumer with old consumer is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using the new consumer by passing [bootstrap-server] instead of [zookeeper].
value1`

Now that we have a topic with a message in it, I run my simple Java kafka consumer code to fetch all messages in the topic 'hellotopic'. Below is the code

```
import java.util.Arrays\;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
public class SampleConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start consumer code");
        Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
         props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
         props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
         props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
         props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
         props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
         KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
         consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("hellotopic"));
         //while (true) {
             ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
             for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                 System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
         //}
         System.out.println("End consumer code");
    }
}
```

When we run the above class, here is the output seen

```
Start consumer code
End consumer code
```

Tried a lot to find the issue, but no luck yet. Much appreciate help on this simple example.

Comment: Welcome SO, looks like you forgot to add you consumer code, it would be easy for the community to help you if you add that information too.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @VikramPalakurthi I have included the consumer code now. Would be great to understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with the code:

1. You are missing a particular config that makes the consumer start from the earliest offset: `props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");`
   The `--from-beginning` in your command line consumer actually translated to this config. This config tells the consumer to start from the earliest offset if there no committed offset found for the corresponding topic and partition within the group.
2. The actual `poll` should be in a loop. One `poll` may not give the consumer enough time to do the subscription and also fetch data. One common way to do the poll  is this:

   ```
   try {
       while (true) {
           ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
           for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
               System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
       }
   } finally {
       consumer.close();
   }
   ```